# JavaScript rejects all my RegExs, how come?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this at the moment, (I found the code on here).

```
     var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
     someText.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

It will replace any http://URL in someText with a proper `<a href>`

But i also require it to match www. without the http. I found this RegEx on RegEx Lib.

```
((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~]*)?
```

And i tested in on the RegEx checker site, http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp

It matches the strings i want. But when i put it into my exp var, JavaScript is blowing up and causing an error.

I even tried newing it up as a new RegExp like so.

```
var exp = new RegExp(((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~]*)?);
```

But the same thing happens.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kohan

Comment: You probably need to escape your escapes. Perhaps even multiple times.

Comment: your question isn't in the slightest bit anything to do with jQuery. The language you're working with is JavaScript, jQuery is a framework written in JavaScript to aid DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Andy E But i am using JQuery which is more telling. There may have been some JQuery function to do this easily for all i know. And by stating JQuery you know i am using JavaScript, but if i tagged it with JavaScript, you don't know if im using JQuery.

Comment: there is no jQuery function to make it easier. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the RegExp constructor takes a string as argument, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

So just put quotes around your regexp and it should work fine.

```
var exp = new RegExp("((http\\://|https\\://|ftp\\://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\\.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\\?\\.'~]*)?");
someText.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: He also needs to "double escape", by escaping the escape character. For example, wherever you see `\.` you actually need `\\.`.

Comment: Putting my original expression into new RegExp(" "); causes it to no longer work. But my new reg exp does now do something (not what i was expecting but another problem i suspect). What is the difference between my first expression and the second one that i need to put into the new RegExp()?

Comment: @Kohan first one is a regex literal - where the regex is enclosed in two slashes like `/regex/`. You don't have to escape backslashes in a regex literal - but you should escape forwards slashes as it is the delimiter. The second one is regex constructor which takes pattern as a string and hence no delimiter is required - neither should you escape forward slashes. But being a string, you gotta escape the backslashes in it

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you've got the JavaScript syntax straightened out, now let's talk about *regex* syntax.  The colon (`:`) has no special meaning, so there's no need to escape it.  The dot (`.`) and question mark (`?`) normally do have special meanings, but not when they appear in a character class (i.e., inside the square brackets).

The hyphen (`-`) *does* have special meaning in a character class: it forms ranges, like `[a-z]` and `[0-9]`.  If you want to include a literal hyphen in a character class, you either escape it with a backslash or place it at the beginning or end of the list.  For example, in `[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]` the final hyphen matches a hyphen, while the other three are used to form ranges.  (The backslash in front of the dot is unnecessary, but it doesn't harm anything.)

Now look at `[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~]`.  The backslashes in front of `?` and `.` are just clutter, but that foruth hyphen is a real problem.  It forms a range starting with `/` and ending with `_`; if you look at an ASCII character map, you'll see that it includes the digits `0-9` and uppercase letters `A-Z`, plus

`/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`

...obviously not what the author intended.  There's also a lot of unnecessary grouping and duplicate code in that regex, and do you really need to match IP addresses, too?  The moral is: don't trust anything you find on RegExLib.com.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation there. +1. Looks like i should read into making my own regex then.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression in javascript must be surrounded by slashes '/', so it will look like

```
var expr = /pattern/flags;
```

for you the corect way is

```
var exp = /((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~]*)?/;
```

If you use the constructor new RegExp(), call it in a form

```
var expr = new RegExp(pattern [, flags]);
```

here pattern and flags are string params

```
var exp = new RegExp("((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~]*)?");
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the forward-slashes in the regex literal, and the backslashes in the string version.